# MATLAB ttest2 command gives different values when used on same data in a 2D and 3D matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, statistics

I'm using MATLAB to perform some statistics on some data. I have two 17x206x378 matrices where dimension 1 are subjects from the same group (so 17 subjects in matrix1, 17 in matrix 2). I want to perform ttests so I get 206 p-values. I then want to do this SEPARATELY for each of the 378 elements in the third dimension.

So say u is a 17x206x378 matrix and d is a different 17x206x378 matrix.
I basically started by doing:
    `[h,p,ci,s] = ttest2(u,d)`

Which does in fact give me a p-matrix size 1x206x378 so everything looked great.

Then to do a quick check I just extracted the first of the third dimension elements from each matrix with:
    `u1=u(:,:,1); d1=d(:,:,1);`

and ran test2 on this data via what you would expect:
    `[h1,p1,ci1,s1] = ttest2(u1,d1);`

I again got a 1x206 p1-matrix of results but the values are not the same as those in the 1x206x378 p-matrix. When I plot the values in both the p(:,:,1) and the p1 vectors the resulting plots look very similar but not exactly the same.
Obviously one of these give results that are significant (below .05) in some instances where the other does not and I do not want to report a fake result so 2 questions I suppose?

1) I am under the impression I am doing the ttests on the same data so what exactly is going on here?
2) If I do ultimately want to get 206 p-values for each of the 378 third dimension elements, what is the correct way to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following code:

```
u = rand(17,206,378);
d = rand(17,206,378);
u1 = u(:,:,1);
d1 = d(:,:,1);
[h,p,ci,s] = ttest(u,d);
[h1,p1,ci1,s1] = ttest(u1,d1);
sum(abs(p1(1,:)- p(1,:,1)))
```

And the output was 0, indicating that the corresponding elements of p and p1 are the same.  Maybe it's an indexing issue.